# Compiler warnings from K&R program

Tags: c, warnings

I believe I copied this code verbatim from the book. It works, but generates three warnings:

C4047: 'function' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [1000]'

C4024: 'copy' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2

C4028: formal parameter 2 different from declaration

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 //max input line size

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from);

//print longest input line
main()
{
    int len;    //current line length
    int max;    //max length seen so far
    char line[MAXLINE]; //current input line
    char longest[MAXLINE];  //longest line saved here

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    //there was a line
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}
//getline: read a line into s, return length
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
//copy: copy 'from into 'to'; assume to is big enough
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Typo questions are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the forward declaration on the fifth line you have this:

```
void copy(char to[], char from); // <<== No square brackets
```

and in the definition you have this:

```
void copy(char to[], char from[]) ...
```

The definition is correct; the forward declaration is not. You need to add square brackets to forward declaration to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much dasblinkenlight!